# Rotate each face on their own axis in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made a setup that kinda works, it's on the screenshot, but it feels like some of the faces are not rotating exactly on their axis, axes on those faces are displaced a little, it creates wavy effect when I rotate it, do i do something wrong?

[image: ball]

Comment: I need to do the same thing, the "Field on domain" node no longer exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The center of the rotation needs to be the face position. $\left ( 0, 0, 0 \right )$ is the origin of the object.

You can capture the position of faces to use it on other domains:

[image]

or in Blender 3.3 you can use the *Field on Domain* node:

[image]

---

- In Blender 3.4, *Field on Domain* is now *Interpolate Domain*.
- In Blender 3.5, *Field on Domain* is now *Evaluate on Domain*.

Comment: That works, thanks

Comment: Was Field on Domain node removed? I can only find Field on Index in blender 3.4 - is the solution different for blender 3.4?